# Use additional *trainable* variables in Keras/Tensorflow custom loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I know how to write a custom loss function in Keras with additional input, not the standard `y_true`, `y_pred` pair, see below. My issue is inputting the loss function with a *trainable* variable (a few of them) which is part of the loss gradient and should therefore be updated.

My workaround is:

- Enter the network a dummy input of `N`X`V` size where `N` is the number of observations and `V` number of additional variables
- Add a `Dense()` layer `dummy_output` so that Keras will track my `V` "weights"
- Use this layer's `V` weights in my custom loss function for my true output layer
- Use a dummy loss function (simply returns 0.0 and/or has weight 0.0) for this `dummy_output` layer so my `V` "weights" are only updated via my custom loss function

**My question is:** Is there a more natural Keras/TF-like way of doing this? Because it feels so contrived not to mention prone to bugs.

Example of my workaround:

**(Yes I know this is a very silly custom loss function, in reality things are much more complex)**

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras import Model

n_col = 10
n_row = 1000
X = np.random.normal(size=(n_row, n_col))
beta = np.arange(10)
y = X @ beta

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# my custom loss function accepting my dummy layer with 2 variables
def custom_loss_builder(dummy_layer):
    def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        var1 = dummy_layer.trainable_weights[0][0]
        var2 = dummy_layer.trainable_weights[0][1]
        return var1 * K.mean(K.square(y_true-y_pred)) + var2 ** 2 # so var2 should get to zero, var1 should get to minus infinity?
    return custom_loss

# my dummy loss function
def dummy_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 0.0

# my dummy input, N X V, where V is 2 for 2 vars
dummy_x_train = np.random.normal(size=(X_train.shape[0], 2)) 

# model
inputs = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1],))
dummy_input = Input(shape=(dummy_x_train.shape[1],))
hidden1 = Dense(10)(inputs) # here only 1 hidden layer in the "real" network, assume whatever network is built here
output = Dense(1)(hidden1)
dummy_output = Dense(1, use_bias=False)(dummy_input)
model = Model(inputs=[inputs, dummy_input], outputs=[output, dummy_output])

# compilation, notice zero loss for the dummy_output layer
model.compile(
  loss=[custom_loss_builder(model.layers[-1]), dummy_loss],
  loss_weights=[1.0, 0.0], optimizer= 'adam')

# run, notice y_train repeating for dummy_output layer, it will not be used, could have created dummy_y_train as well
history = model.fit([X_train, dummy_x_train], [y_train, y_train],
                    batch_size=32, epochs=100, validation_split=0.1, verbose=0,
                   callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)])
```

Seems to work as indeed whatever the start values for `var1` and `var2` (the initialization of the `dummy_output` layer) they aspire for minus `inf` and `0` respectively:

(this plot comes from running the model iteratively and saving those two weights like below)

```py
var1_list = []
var2_list = []
for i in range(100):
    if i % 10 == 0:
        print('step %d' % i)
    model.fit([X_train, dummy_x_train], [y_train, y_train],
              batch_size=32, epochs=1, validation_split=0.1, verbose=0)
    var1, var2 = model.layers[-1].get_weights()[0]
    var1_list.append(var1.item())
    var2_list.append(var2.item())

plt.plot(var1_list, label='var1')
plt.plot(var2_list, 'r', label='var2')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "part of the loss gradient"? Since the net effect of the loss gradient is essentially backpropagating through the model and change the trainable model weights, does this implies that your `var1` and `var2` in the custom loss function can actually be derived from the layer weights (and perhaps, biases)?

Comment: The variables are are unknown parameters which are involved in creating the observed data. As such they are part of the (very complex) loss function and the model attempts to find a link between X and y given these unknown parameters which are also to be estimated. Part of the loss function, therefore part of the gradient as seen in my silly example. The real model is more interesting and makes sense.

Comment: Nice. In any case, as long as the update of loss function parameters happens right after training, then keras Callback will still be the canonical way to go. How to calculate the loss function parameters lies beyond the scope of this question. As long as you know how to update the closure variables, you can make it work in keras Callbacks as demonstrated in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question here, after days of struggling I got it to work without dummy input, I think this is much better and should be the "canonical" way until Keras/TF simplify the process. This is how the Keras/TF docs do it [here](https://tensorflow.google.cn/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#handling_losses_and_metrics_that_dont_fit_the_standard_signature).

The key to using a loss function with external *trainable* variable is through working with a custom loss/output **Layer** which has `self.add_loss(...)` in its `call()` implementation, like so:

```py
class MyLoss(Layer):
    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        super(MyLoss, self).__init__()
        self.var1 = K.variable(var1) # or tf.Variable(var1) etc.
        self.var2 = K.variable(var2)
    
    def get_vars(self):
        return self.var1, self.var2
    
    def custom_loss(self, y_true, y_pred):
        return self.var1 * K.mean(K.square(y_true-y_pred)) + self.var2 ** 2
    
    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        self.add_loss(self.custom_loss(y_true, y_pred))
        return y_pred
```

Now notice the `MyLoss` layer needs **two** inputs, the actual `y_true` and the predicted `y` until that point:

```py
inputs = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1],))
y_input = Input(shape=(1,))
hidden1 = Dense(10)(inputs)
output = Dense(1)(hidden1)
my_loss = MyLoss(0.5, 0.5)(y_input, output) # here can also initialize those var1, var2
model = Model(inputs=[inputs, y_input], outputs=my_loss)

model.compile(optimizer= 'adam')
```

Finally as TF docs mention, in this case you do not have to specify the `loss` or `y` in the `fit()` function:

```py
history = model.fit([X_train, y_train], None,
                    batch_size=32, epochs=100, validation_split=0.1, verbose=0,
                    callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)])
```

Again, notice that `y_train` comes into `fit()` as one of the inputs.

Now it works:

```py
var1_list = []
var2_list = []
for i in range(100):
    if i % 10 == 0:
        print('step %d' % i)
    model.fit([X_train, y_train], None,
              batch_size=32, epochs=1, validation_split=0.1, verbose=0)
    var1, var2 = model.layers[-1].get_vars()
    var1_list.append(var1.numpy())
    var2_list.append(var2.numpy())

plt.plot(var1_list, label='var1')
plt.plot(var2_list, 'r', label='var2')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

(I should also mention this specific pattern of `var1`, `var2` highly depends on their initial values, if `var1`'s initial value is higher than 1 it will not in fact decrease until minus `inf`)

Comment: This looks canonical indeed! If I have read it correctly, inheriting from `Layer` would allow automated gradient backpropagation that is not available for `Callback`s. Therefore I deleted my post to not mislead others.

Comment: I liked your post actually.

Comment: It's my pleasure! I think it's very nice that we both have learned a little more from the great Keras infrastructure. `Callbacks` are meant for pre- and post-backpropagation actions so does not fit your current need properly. I think it is right to delete it because this is an Q&A site, not a discussion forum after all :)